# Undefined method `negative?' for Fixnum

Tags: ruby

In local development environment of a Ruby on Rails application, I get:

```
2147483647.negative? # => false
```

After deployment, I get this error:

```
undefined method `negative?' for 2147483647:Fixnum
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you must be using ruby `2.1` at production and `2.3`+ at development. please update your ruby version in production or development

Comment: Thanks @HaseebEqx, it worked